# How can I run react native application in widnows 10?

Tags: android, react-native

[image]Hope evrything is fine.

I am trying to learn react nattive.

I have windows 10 machine.

Hyper -v Is not supported.

So When I try to run my android application  using react-native run-android

I am getting the following error  in console

Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..

Also my command show loading dependecny graph, doen

How can I fix the Error and make Android Emulator Works in windows 10 ?

If I run emualtor from Android Studio

I get [image]

Answer (score 1):

First start the emulator and only then run the application and make sure points given below:
1) Only one emulator running at a time
2) Don't start emulator if USB device is connected